# Show solved real time notification for chosen non favorite questions

Tags: discussion, notifications

**Feature Request**

Very often there are questions to which I have no answer. But I would like to know how to solve the problem.

Current i have this three options, to "subscribe" the question:

1. **I mark it as favorite.**

   *- Anyway I will get no solved notification. So I have to check the status manually.*

   *- Also, I don't really want to have hundreds of favorites...*

   *- There is a risk that I just forget to check the status of the issue.*
2. **I open it in a new browser tab and check from time to time for new answers**

   *No really elegant solution*
3. **Use Rss Feed**

   *- I will get notification on every change. Thanks, but I just want to get notification if issue is solved (accepted answer)*

   *- Not applicable with many devices without plugins or rss management clients.*

   *- Also rss means I/client ask the server about news. This feature request means to get notifications **from the server** like notification about new Answer, new comment etc...*

   *- **I have also remove the rss feed after issue was solved. It is to complicated. It is not user friendly.***

As you can see, there is no way to get such **real time** notifications **from the server**. This feature would help me to learn more.

Comment: it is very hard to discuss, since you get downvoted without real arguments. no discussion is allowed... But hey, "power" users have their say.

Comment: ...Or put a bounty on it, which will get you notifications for new answers

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta#help-post-body). People simply disagree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

When viewing your favorites those that have seen activity since you last looked at them are highlighted, allowing you to more easily check for updates.

Additionally, all questions have an RSS feed that you can subscribe to:

> [image]

Comment: So if change the browser I have to add rss feed again? I'm using 3 PC's (notebook, macbook, PC)... Should I add rss feed for every device? OK i could use some plugins to share rss feeds... No this is not a elegant solution. I mean it should be a technology-independent notification.

Comment: @dit So you want to have a personal assistant that does nothing but tell you when your favorites questions have been answered?  How do you plan to have a website convey information to you without using any technology?

Comment: no no what I mean is to get solved notification. just like notification about new answer on my question. I mean i get this notification not from rss, it get it from server.

Comment: @dit Data from an RSS feed comes from the server.  Where else do you think it would come from?

Comment: I know, but initiated by a client. Client ask the server "something new?". I you have other information about how rss works, please enlighten me on.

Comment: @dit Yes, the client is requesting information *from the server*.  I fail to see how that is either a problem, or how any proposed solution would be any different.

Comment: Sorry hard to explain. I mean notification in the header over websockets or something like that...

Comment: @dit Why is that any better than an RSS feed?

Comment: cause I'm using multiple devices + stackoverflow app. I'm using multiple browsers and dont want to install additional plugin rss sharing apps to make rss available on every device. You will get a message about THIS comment WITHOUT rss feed. This is nice, isn't that so?

Comment: @dit So you know how to get exactly the functionality that you want, you just don't want to be bothered spending a minute setting it up (even though it would have taken you far less effort than it would have to have simply asked this question)?  There are *lots* of ways of accessing RSS feeds from multiple devices.  This is not a new/underdeveloped technology.  If you just can't be bothered to do it, then apparently you don't need this functionality that badly.

Comment: I try it again... You will get a message about THIS comment in the stackexchange header WITHOUT rss feed. This is nice, isn't that so?

Comment: @dit That's not at all relevant to my statements.  You have a solution to your problem.  You're *choosing* to ignore it.  If you want to start using it, you can, and it'll be there waiting for you.

Comment: your solution is your statement your opinion. thx for this.  Check my question. I explained why this is not a good solution - it is just a WORKAROUND. I's all about progress. I'm suggest a new feature, to make the user experience better.

Comment: @dit It's not a workaround, it's exactly why RSS feeds exist as a feature.  Again, it does everything that you need it to do.  If you don't actually care about getting this information, then that's fine, but if you want to, you can.

Comment: ok it makes no sense. it is the best time for me to give up. this issue needs some OPEN minds.

Comment: @dit You can use a service like [feedly](https://feedly.com) to get the same feeds on multiple devices (and browsers) without having to subscribe on each device. This is just *one* example of the many ways you can get what you are looking for.

Comment: @Louis I'm looking for real time notification from stackexchange server not for rss services. Read my question.

Comment: @dit Well, then I really don't see why you keep harping on "multiple devices" in your response to the suggestion to use RSS in your comments here.

Comment: @Louis have i to login on feedly to get get my feeds?